# What is meant by the statement that std::declval cannot be called?

Tags: c++, std, declval

On the [cppreference-page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) for `std::declval` it says the following:

> Return value

> Cannot be called and thus never returns a value.

What does this mean? Surely we call it when we use it?

```
struct Foo { int func(){}  };

decltype(std::declval<Foo>().func()) integer;
/*                        ^
                          |                      */
```

Comment: `decltype(std::declval<Foo>().func())` never calls `declval`, it only looks at the return value.

Comment: @DrewDormann Are you sure? I think @tkausl is more correct, that `std::declval` cannot be called and `decltype` just looks at the type of the return value

Comment: @JensB You may not *evaluate* `std::declval` which basically means execution is never allowed try to run the function. Normally a compiler will produce an error if you try.

Comment: I think what's key to any answer here is that any expression inside `decltype()` is _inspected_, but not _evaluated_.  The "call" indicated in this code sample _looks like a call_, but actually is never called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The program is ill-formed if `std::declval<T>` is odr-used. However, cppreference tries to phrase this in a way that most users will find easier to understand.

A call to a function, or taking the address of the function, will normally odr-use that function. However, this is only the case if the call/address is actually *evaluated*. Thus, it is legal to call `std::declval<T>` as long as the call isn't evaluated. (Note that it's not enough merely to prove that the call will never occur at runtime. Rather, the call must occur in certain types of contexts in which the rules of the language prevent it from being evaluated. Therefore, the compiler can always check this condition.)

`decltype` does not evaluate its operand, so it is usually legal to place a call to `std::declval<T>` inside `decltype`. However, there are some situations where parts of the operand are evaluated anyway. For example, `decltype(std::array<int, std::declval<int>()>)` won't compile, because it will try to evaluate `std::declval<int>()` in order to get the size of the array.